# Flutter Google maps polylines from current location to another location

Tags: flutter, google-maps, polyline

I am trying to draw polyline from my current location to another location in flutter, all the examples I have seen online doesn't have a problem with this part of the code.

```
  void setPolylines() async {
    List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
        googleAPIKey,
        currentLocation.latitude,
        currentLocation.longitude,
        destinationLocation.latitude,
        destinationLocation.longitude);
```

This code above is giving me the error below

```
A value of type 'PolylineResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<PointLatLng>'.

Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<PointLatLng>'.
Open documentation

Too many positional arguments: 3 expected, but 5 found.  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments. Open documentation
```

Comment: What Flutter package are you using to draw the Polylines? And what version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [flutter_polyline_points](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points) package based on the method you used.

Looking at the documentation, it appears that you need to pass the result of `getRouteBetweenCoordinates` method to `PolylineResult` instead of `List<PointLatLng>`

For example:

```
PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(googleAPiKey,
        _originLatitude, _originLongitude, _destLatitude, _destLongitude);
```

Comment: This will be an expensive call, i guess. Is there any simple way to remove the point as user progress towards destination and show the polyline of user current location and destination.